# Reconnecting to a PiCamera stream in python after disconnecting

Tags: python, loops, sockets, raspberry-pi, reconnect

I'm currently trying to program and learn python, while making a project with the raspberry pi zero w. So far I'm just trying to get it to start recording video using picamera in python, as well as stream that video so I can monitor what the output is on my phone. However as it currently stands it only starts recording video once I connect to it via some sort of streaming program. What I'd like for it to do is start recording the video at the start of the program and be able to connect to it whenever I'd like to monitor it. As it stands I can connect to it no problem, but then I'm unable to reconnect to it.

A basic idea of what I'm wanting kinda goes like this.

```
Start Recording
Listen on port 8080
    if connection is started
       start streaming video stream 2 (also known as splitter port)
    else connection ended
       wait for new connection
```

I realize that sounds horrible. I hope it gives the general idea of what I'm trying to do. Like I said I'm just learning python, and only have some basic knowledge in Basic.

Here's my code that I'm currently working with. Like I said, it works, just only when I connect to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import picamera
import datetime as dt
import os.path

filename = 'hauntvideo'
save_path = '/home/pi'
completed_video = os.path.join(save_path, filename)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=DeprecationWarning)

#Camera Setup
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
    camera.framerate = 30
    camera.hflip = True
    camera.vflip = True
#Connection Listening
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')

    try:
        camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264', splitter_port=2, 
resize=(640,360))
        camera.start_recording(completed_video + '{}.h264'.format( 
dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') ), bitrate=4500000)
        camera.wait_recording(7*60*60)
        camera.stop_recording()
    finally:
        connection.close()
        server_socket.close()
        quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

> However as it currently stands it only starts recording video once I connect to it via some sort of streaming program. What I'd like for it to do is start recording the video at the start of the program and be able to connect to it whenever I'd like to monitor it.

This is due to the following line of code:

```
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
```

The accept() function blocks, meaning that it doesn't return until the connection is established. Therefore, the code that starts recording:

```
camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264', ... )
```

only gets executed after the connection is established (after accept() returns).

In order to accomplish what you want, you would need to use threads. In one thread, start recording the video locally, i.e.

```
camera.start_recording(completed_video + '{}.h264'.format( 
dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') ), bitrate=4500000)
```

In another thread, accept an incoming connection, and upon connection call:

```
camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264', splitter_port=2, 
resize=(640,360))
```

> As it stands I can connect to it no problem, but then I'm unable to reconnect to it.

If you want to be able to connect, disconnect, and reconnect indefinitely, then you need to accept the connection in a loop (in its own thread). Perhaps something like this:

```
while(True):
    connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
    camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264', splitter_port=2, 
    resize=(640,360))
    camera.wait_recording(7*60*60) #assuming this records for 7 hours?
```

> I'm currently trying to program and learn python, while making a project with the raspberry pi zero w.

I don't know if you are new to programming in general, or just to python. In the former case, dealing with network programming concepts and threads might be a little bit challenging at first. However, they are necessary to use/understand in order to achieve the functionality you desire.

Comment: I'm very new to programming. I'm quick to pick up basic concepts and somewhat figure what each thing does. However this is my first real stab at python programming.  

  A few things, what do you mean by threads?   

  Also yes the (7*60*60) was to have it record for 7 hours. I want the main video to record for 7 hours, but I'd like to just connect to the stream any time.

Comment: @KillerXtreme
Threads are basic units of code execution - your code traditionally runs from top to bottom, one instruction at a time. If you need more than one thing to happen at once, you need to create additional threads (or processes). This ELI5 post explains it pretty well: [What is a thread...](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/35qw88/eli5_what_is_a_thread_in_a_processor/).

So one thread would start recording the video to your computer, and another thread would be accepting connections. They are two sequences of execution, happening simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, I understand what threads are when it comes to normal computation. I wasn't sure how it's done within python tho. I'll search around. Can you have multiple things running in a single python script? Cause I tried running two separate scripts thinking that'd be the way to do it, and you can't bring up the picamera twice.

Comment: You can have multiple things running inside a python script, if you use threads. Here's a gist I made to demonstrate it for your purposes: [thread_example.py](https://gist.github.com/vpatov/2b68d1d7de8bbad36de6e40b9b18f8c3)
(By the way, if you found my answer useful, give it a vote :) )

Comment: Unfortunately threading has not worked for me. When I try to connect it spits back this to me. https://pastebin.com/WiRdCMYU

Comment: @KillerXtreme based on what you linked, it doesnt look like the error is due to threading. It means your camera is closed. I dont know anything about the software or camera you're using so I can't help you there. Threading is most likely not the cause of that error though.

Comment: Partly yes partly no, It is because of threading, but also a limit of picamera. I found a solution by putting the camera into global and having both threads use it that way. Now I still need to figure out a way to allow socket to be reconnected to. I've gotta figure out the loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

KillerXtreme, This should be the code you were looking for 5 years ago (namely, you can connect and reconnect to this over and over with no hiccups)!
Hope this helps somebody!

```
import socket
import picamera
from threading import Thread

def stop_recording(cam):
    try:
        cam.stop_recording()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
        # print('Error: {}'.format(e))

def camera_setup():
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    camera.framerate = 24
    return camera

def create_socket():
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9090))
    server_socket.listen(0)
    return server_socket

def stream(server_socket, cam):
    connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
    if cam.recording:
        stop_recording(cam)
    cam.start_recording(connection, format='h264', resize=(1024, 768), inline_headers=True)

def stream_video_to_network(cam):
    server_socket = create_socket()
    while True:
        stream(server_socket, cam)

def main(camera):
    Thread(target=stream_video_to_network, args=(camera,)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(camera_setup())
```